# Abrir fichero PHP en SublimeText en explorador web

Tags: php, html, web, sublimetext3, ide

tengo una duda y por más que busco no encuentro la forma, estoy desarrollando una pequeña web, anteriormente utilizaba el Netbeans, tengo varias páginas que no son html, sino php, el detalle es que ahora que me estoy pasando al SublimeText no encuentro una forma de ejecutar mis páginas PHP, he visto en SublimeText que si la página tiene extensión HTML, solo doy click derecho en cualquier lugar de mi código y selecciono "Open in browser" y se ejecuta la página a como lo vería el usuario, pero no es lo mismo con PHP, hay alguna forma de hacerlo directamente desde SublimeText?

Espero me puedan ayudar, me trae de cabeza este problema.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Uso Windows 7, Xampp, Crhome y estoy iniciando con SublimeText 3.

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje de programación que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, por lo que veo parece que lo quieres abrir como un archivo normal. Debes usar un servidor como Wamp o Xampp, apache, Laragon...

Comment: Entonces creo que es incorrecto que mis paginas web tengan la extensión .php verdad? perdón mi ignoracia, según estoy entendiendo los php solo los debo utilizar para procesos en servidor y todo lo demás debe ser HTML. Es que en mi página web el index es index.php, siento que necesito modificar todo a HTML, es correcto?

Comment: Bastaría con que cambies la extensión .php a .html

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, estaba implementado de mala manera los ficheros PHP.

Answer (score 0):

bueno como entiendo tu pregunta es que tenias tu pagina web en netBeans usando HTML5 y PHP para ejecutar la pagina.

y ahora que usas Sublime Text3 pero cuando intentas abrir tus sitios web en PHP
pero no se ven bien?

bueno lo que yo haria es darle permisos al directorio htdocs de xampp para sobre escribir despues copy y paste todos los archivos en el directorio htdocs  organizado en una carpeta llamada por ejemplo sitiowebphp y despues me metiera a localhost/sitiowebphp  y listo podrias ver tu sitio web con php obviamente si estas usando XAMPP y tienes corriendo tu apache2 desde el panel de control de XAMPP.